# Containment of most common vector space of procsses

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Does the space of processes $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}\sup_{t}|X_{t}|^2<\infty$ belong to the space of $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}|X_{t}|^2dt<\infty$. I cant find couterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
\begin{align*}
E\left[\int_0^T |X_t|^2 dt \right] &\leq E\left[\int_0^T \sup_{s \in [0,T]} |X_s|^2 dt \right] \\
&= T E\left[\sup_{s \in [0, T]} |X_s|^2 \right] < \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Let $T$ be fixed, let $M(\omega) = \sup_{t\in[0,T]} |X(t,\omega)|^2.$ Then for each $\omega$, $|X(t,\omega)|^2 \leq M(\omega)$, or $f(t,\omega) = M(\omega) - \sup_{t\in[0,T]} |X(t,\omega)|^2 \geq 0$ for all $\omega$ and all $t \in [0, T]$. In particular, $\int_0^T f(t,\omega) dt \geq 0$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand that. What does it imply?

Comment: @Probably  It implies the inequality you asked about before you deleted your comment.

Comment: the integral of $M$ dont need to be finite, does it?

Comment: It is finite, almost surely. Since $E M < \infty$, $M < \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Consider $\frac{1}{x}$ on $[0,1]$ finite a.e but integral not finite.

Comment: I did not say $M < \infty \Rightarrow E M < \infty$, I said $E M <\infty \Rightarrow M < \infty$ a.s. I think I am done with this conversation and this question and will avoid responding more in comments, as it seems you have everything needed to answer the question if you read the statements carefully.